# sliding animations using angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a [webpage](https://rollneat.herokuapp.com/) designed using `angular 2` that has an animation for transition on X scale translation. It works fine, as explained in details on the official [angular animations page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html).

Basically I am translating an `md-card` in dom. This is how I am doing it:

`component.html`:

```
<md-content class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="center start">
  <div flex="30" layout="column" flex-xs="100">
    <md-card *ngFor="let spinItem of spinnerItems" [@flyInOut]="'in'">
      <md-card-header>
        <img src="assets/Cherry-80.png" md-card-avatar>
        <div class="md-card-header-text">
          <md-card-title>RollnEat</md-card-title>
          <md-card-subtitle>Take away and dine-in</md-card-subtitle>
        </div>
      </md-card-header>
        <img src="assets/background-image-1.jpg" md-card-image>
      <md-card-title>
        <span class="md-headline">{{spinItem}}</span>
      </md-card-title>
      <md-card-content>
        <p>
          content comes here
        </p>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

`component.js`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      state('in', style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({
          opacity: 0,
          transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
        }),
        animate('0.2s ease-in')
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate('0.2s 10 ease-out', style({
          opacity: 0,
          transform: 'translateX(100%)'
        }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})

export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit {

  arrItems : string[] = ['Bob', 'faizan', 'raza'];
  spinnerItems : string[];
  constructor() {
    this.spinnerItems = [];
    let intervalSeconds = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 5;
    let delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

    let totalNumOfExecutions = (intervalSeconds * 1000) / 500;
    let numOfExecutions = 0;
    let intervalStartSpinning = setInterval(() => {
      this.spinnerItems.push(this.arrItems[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.arrItems.length)]);
      delay(300).then(() => {
        if (numOfExecutions != (totalNumOfExecutions - 1))
          this.spinnerItems.pop();
        numOfExecutions++;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(intervalStartSpinning);
    }, intervalSeconds * 1000);

  }
}
```

**TO DO:**

I know its some css/html caveats that is involved, but I want to design/place the cards, such that they somewhat remotely resemble the following samples:

[image: image sample slider 1]

[image: image sample slider 2]

Comment: I think this kind of effect is called cover flow .Maybe this will help https://github.com/fanktom/angular-coverflow

Comment: This could be a challenge -- to make a coverflow powered by angular 2. I think we can start with [Bootstrap's carousel](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/) and replace the pictures with md-cards and add translations. It could be fun.